# Cloud Firestore: Same document on different query. Is it charged as separated read?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've read the documentation about how `write`, `read` in Firebase is charged.

Let's say I have a 20 item of todo list with `project_id` as a key.

- `todosRef.onSnapshot()` will be counted as `20 reads`.
- I updated a todo with new property. `todosRef.onSnapshot()` will return new 20 item, but because the other 19 `doc` request is cached—it only counts as 1 read. So right now the total is `21 reads`.

My question is: What if user queried `todosRef.where('project_id', '==', yourSpecificProjId)`. Is it considered a new `n read`—or there will be no new reads (because it's the same todo `doc` is unchanged and cached on first query above)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it returns the same document that was previously cached and unchanged, there is no read charge.  The local cache applies to all queries.