# How to get a DocumentSnapshot for a specific document out of a QuerySnapshot?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

To make things simple, let's say I've got two screens:

- `StoriesListScreen`
- `StoryDetailsScreen`

To populate `StoriesListScreen` I fetch some data from Firestore, using a `Stream`:

```dart
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getFirstTenStories() {
    return _firestore.collection('stories').limit(10).snapshots();
}
```

I then use this `Stream` in a `StreamBuilder` in `StoriesListScreen` and map the documents it contains to some `Story` objects. I then use a `ListView.builder` which creates some `StoriesListTile` objects taking a `Story` object as a parameter so that they can render each object in the list.

So all is well...

But when the user clicks on a `StoriesListTile`, I would like to open the `StoryDetailsScreen` and show the details of that specific `Story` object.

Since the `Story` object exists at this point and has already been passed in the `StoriesListTile` object, I can easily pass in this `Story` object to the `StoryDetailsScreen`:

```dart
 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StoryDetailsScreen(_story));
```

So it works fine, but...

I would like to be able to listen to any change in the data used to create the `Story` object.

At the moment if my data change in Firestore then my list in `StoriesListScreen` will automatically be updated because it uses a `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`.

I would like to do the same in `StoryDetailsScreen` but what I pass to the `StoryDetailsScreen` screen is not a `Stream`, it is a `Story` object that will not be updated.

One solution could be to fetch this story data from Firestore and use the `Stream<DocumentSnapshot>` in a `StreamBuilder` in `StoryDetailsScreen`, so it will be automatically updated if the data changes. But that would mean wasting another Firestore read because I already have this data.

So how can I pass in a `Stream<DocumentSnapshot>` for a specific Document to my `StoryDetailsScreen`? Is it possible to extract it from the `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` I already have?

Answer (score 0):

I really like this question, you are making me reconsider how I've written my app and I'm now wondering if there is a better way now too. Thanks for that!

I think that fundamentally this problem is about separating out the business logic (the data in the streams) from the UI (which page is currently loaded).

I'd look at using [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and create a service that serves up a stream that any of the widgets in the app can access. This way you have a single service that is listening for changes, updating the data and everything else in the app listens to that stream.

Is this what you were looking for?

***Edit***

Do you get charged for a stream that is listening for changes to the database?

The answer is, 'It depends' This is from the [Cloud Fire-Store Billing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).

**Listening to query results**

Cloud Firestore allows you to listen to the results of a query and get realtime updates when the query results change.

When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is deleted, you are not charged for a read.)

Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, David!

Yes, using a Provider could be a good idea, I am already using some app-level repository to get the data. But the issue would be to serve a Stream which is only listening to one document's changes, while the Provider still listens to a Stream of a collection of document.

But another question would be whether you would be charged one more read if you fetch a document from Firestore even if you had already fetched it before (as part of a QuerySnapshot) and this document has not changed since.

My issue here is trying to get as much cost efficient as I can.

Comment: Thanks! 

I had checked the doc a couple of times, but they don't get an explicit answer for this very scenario.

But I finally found a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045198/cloud-firestore-same-document-on-different-query-is-it-charged-as-separated-re

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you mind marking the question as answered?